# Keep honoring javax.validation.constraints.* annotations when switching to jakarta in Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bean-validation, jakarta-migration

We are migrating to spring boot 3 and with that, to jakarta-ee.

I followed https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#jakarta-ee , but I am not sure how to proceed with following problem:

- is there any way to keep honoring javax.validation.constraints.* annotations while switching to jakarta?

Our usecase:

- we have shared Pojo-Libraries that describes objects that are shared between client & servers. For example for common representations between REST interfaces or for event-models sent over Kafka as JSON
- the event-models describe some guarantees such as "this field is nullable, this one is non-null", etc. and have e.g. `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` annotations
- clients typically use these pojos not just for desesializing but might rely on the validation aspects such as reject payload when not adhering to the validations

How would a client that wants to move to jakarta-ee still use `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`?

Comment: Had you figured out a way around this? I have the same problem - my DTOs are used by spring boot 2 and 3 apps. I was thinking of adding both annotations.

Comment: Unfortunately not. 

In our org, teams now decide if they go forward to jakarta only and services stuck on boot 2 do not get field updates OR if they maintain a fork that they port backwards

Answer (score 0):

javax will not work with boot 3, just switch to jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull, the whole point of Spring 6 ( Boot 3 ), Tomcat 10, and Hibernate Validator is to retire javax packages and replace them with jakarta. Newer versions of these libraries are NOT compatible with javax packages.

Even from the link that you shared in your question it says: "*if you should always be using jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api and not javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api.
As well as dependency coordinate changes, Jakarta EE now uses jakarta packages rather than javax. Once you’ve update your dependencies you may find that **>>import statements in your project need to be updated<<**.*"

The validation works the same in newer versions of Hibernate Validator, there is no point in trying to stay on the removed version of annotation, which is no longer present or compatible.

Comment: I get that they want to retire them. What I am looking for is a softer migration path if it is just about the validation-annotations. Not looking to stay on it.

Comment: There is no migration software path, you upgrade everything and replace imports that were javax to jakarta, after that you run all your tests suites, and if they pass, you are good to go.
As I stated before @NotNull from jakarta does the same thing that were javax doing, so you would be "honoring" them as you said.

Comment: It is not as simple as a search&replace for my usecase. We have pojo "libraries" shared by hundreds of services and these have the validation annotation. 

If a service upgrades and still uses an older version (by accident or because the lib for a given model was not updated), the service will simply start and just pass all validations even if the payload is malformed. I would like to know if there is any way for me to still go through validation regardless of javax.validation.NotNull or jakarta.validation.NotNull

Comment: I know it is not simple, migration to newer version of anything is a few months job. Your project will not work if it has javax imports because by definition Spring boot 3 and Spring 6 are working only with jakarta imports, you cannot run your application using old libraries, that is the whole point of upgrading and retiring javax imports. If you remove old dependencies which are javax, and add new ones which are jakarta in your maven/gradle/whatever, your project will not compile in the first place since it would be looking for old library which is no longer present.

Comment: The only validation that will work with your Spring boot 3 is jakarta, you cannot run javax on newest version of Spring, if by some miracle it manages to compile and run, you will get an exception from your application complaining about javax imports, the validation will not only fail, the whole flow will fail due to the old library. I do not understand which part of "you need to replace javax with jakarta", is not clear. You cannot have both of them in the latest spring. If you have javax you will get an exception one way or another, no validation will "go through".

Answer (score -3):

Adding "spring-boot-starter-validation" solved my problem.
You can find it at https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1979.